# How to send messages to handheld and back to android wear in different Intents in android wear?

Tags: android, android-intent, wear-os

I am working on a android app which sends messages to hand held via two different Intents in the wear. I tried googling but the first 50 results did not provide a solution.Any help architecture /code wise would be helpful.

Comment: did you try this: http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html ?

Comment: Yes, I read it. But its really hard to understand how the data is transmitted. To and from the device and the wear.